# How can I copy a range of files depending on a timestamp in the filename?

Tags: bash, timestamp, copy, range, filenames

The OS is Raspberian - linux - Bash.

I'm trying to copy a selection of files depending on the timestamp in their filename and a label from directory A to directory B.

The format of the filenames is:

1. Fixed text: `DCS-932L`
2. The timestamp: YYYYMMDDhhmmssnn
3. Label `_day` or `_night` or `_light_is_on`
4. Fixed text: `.jpg`

So for example:

- `DCS-932L2019103013414701_day.jpg`
- `DCS-932L2019111505255401_night.jpg`
- `DCS-932L2019112319413501_light_is_on.jpg`

How can I copy a certain range of files between 2 given timestamps and, if possible, with one or more given labels ?

I suppose it can been done with `find` or `rsync` in combination with RegEx. But this is so complex it's above my head.

Comment: How many files are expected to be selected ? For large number of files, might be important to minimize number of cp/rsync calls.

Comment: That will be about 3000 files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple time ranges you can use bash's globbing. You might want to activate `shopt -s nullglob`.
Some examples:

```
cp  DCS-932L2019*.jpg          target/dir/  # range = "in 2019"
cp  DCS-932L201911*.jpg        target/dir/  # range = "in november 2019"
cp  DCS-932L2019110*.jpg       target/dir/  # range = "from 2019-11-01 to 2019-11-09"
cp  DCS-932L2019{04..12}*.jpg  target/dir/  # range = "from 2019-04-01 to 2019-12-31"
```

Globbing also works with labels.

```
DCS-932*_day.jpg                # all files with _day label
DCS-932L2019*{_day,_night}.jpg  # all files from 2019 with _day or _night label
```

For arbitrary ranges you have to filter your files manually. This can be done with a loop. The loop can be combined with globbing to speed up the process or to select only some labels.

```
prefix=DCS-932
for file in "$prefix"*.jpg; do
    withoutPrefix="${file/$prefix/}"
    timestamp="${withoutPrefix/_*/}"
    # replace YYYYM... with your range
    (( timestamp > YYYYMMDDhhmmss )) && 
    (( timestamp < YYYYMMDDhhmmss )) &&
    cp "$file" target/dir/
done
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into that tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

Given large number of files, may be important to get efficiency with parallel processing, and issuing small number of 'cp' calls. Combining find/awk/xargs/cp:

```
from=...  # Timestamp ni YYYYMMDDhhmmss
to=...    # Timestamp in YYYYMMDDhhmmss
prefix=DCS-932
find . -name "${prefix}*.jpg" |
    awk -v "FROM=${prefix}${from}" -v TO="${prefix}${to}" '$1 > FROM && $1 < TO' |
    xargs -L50 cp -t target/dir
```

This will use find to locate the files, awk to filter, and xargs to group them to minimize number of cp calls.

In theory, possible to run the copy in parallel (xargs -P4, etc.), but need actual testing.